# How to loop through elements (one field) in the mySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

How to write PHP code to access the first element till last element of the column Website and to pass the output to another php function.

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "wte");

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$query = "SELECT Website FROM websites";

if ($result = $mysqli->query($query)) {

// PHP code to access the first element till last element of the column Website and to pass the output to another php function  

    }

    /* free result set */
    $result->close();
}

/* close connection */
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read php manual: http://php.net//manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      your_function($row["Website"]);
}
```